# Deserialize XML with HTML-escaped part using SimpleXML

Tags: android, xml, retrofit, simple-framework, html-escape-characters

I have an XML that looks something like this:

```
<xml>
&lt;example&gt;&lt;string&gt;test&lt;/string&gt;&lt;/example&gt;
</xml>
```

Is it possible to make SimpleXML restore those HTML-escaped characters during deserialization and continue as usual, inflating these classes:

```
@Root
public class Xml {

    @Element
    public Example example;
}

public class Example {

    @Element
    public String string;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, I think I got it

SimpleXML parses escaped sequence as a `@Text`, which I can use in [constructor injection](http://simple.sourceforge.net/download/stream/doc/tutorial/tutorial.php#immutable), and in that constructor I create another instance of `Persister`, which reads this sequence. Here is the code for the example in the question:

```
@Root
public class Xml {
    @Text
    String text;

    public Example example;

    public Xml(@Text String text) {
        Serializer serializer = new Persister();
        try {
            example = serializer.read(Example.class, text);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

public class Example {

    @Element
    public String string;
}
```

What is interesting is that I don't need to restore escaped characters, SimpleXML does that for me.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58980482/de-serialize-html-escape-characters-using-simple-xml-converter-in-retrofit-andro?noredirect=1#comment104214034_58980482

Comment: Can you just look into it. I got stucked here

Comment: Can we read a blank xml tag exist using simple xml; I want to get 'read' exist for a status; xml below <messageInfo> <duration>2040</duration> <read /> </messageInfo>

Comment: I am always getting error while parsing additional details and its object : <Group><startIndex>1</startIndex><numberOfRecords>40</numberOfRecords><groupDirectory><directoryDetails><firstName>test</firstName><additionalDetails><mobile>test</mobile><title>CTO</title></additionalDetails></directoryDetails><directoryDetails><firstName>test</firstName><additionalDetails><mobile>test</mobile></additionalDetails></directoryDetails><directoryDetails><firstName>test</firstName></directoryDetails></groupDirectory></Group>