# De serialize html escape characters using simple xml converter in retrofit android

Tags: android, xml, retrofit, converters, simple-xml-converter

How can we deserialize html escape characters in inner tags of xml of a response body to be saved in POJO classes using simple xml converter in retrofit android?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<sample>
  <outer>
    &lt;test&gt;data<&lt;/test>&gt;
  </outer>
</sample>
```

Comment: Did you try anything to convert the `xml` to `POJO`?

Comment: Yeah, simple xml converter as converter factory in retrofit

Comment: Plain xml is converted. But sometimes escape characters comes in between in inner tags of xml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it

```
@Root
public class Sample {
    @Element
    Outer outer;
}

public class Outer {
    @Text
    String text;

    public Test test;

    public Xml(@Text String text) {
        Serializer serializer = new Persister();
        try {
            example = serializer.read(Test.class, text);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

public class Test {

    @Element
    public String data;
}
```

Comment: I tried. It returns null. Are you sure it will work with simple xml 2.7.1?

Comment: Check your input, I think it might be malformed. Correct one would look like this:

`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<sample>
  <outer>
    &lt;test&gt;data&lt;/test&gt;
  </outer>
</sample>`

Comment: Here, that compiles and works correctly for me: https://pastebin.com/u5F3334J

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope"
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
 <soap:Body>
  <DetailsResponse xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
   <DetailsResult>&lt;SampleDocument Protocol="KELP"
    Version="1.0"&gt;&lt;serverDetails
    Success="True"&gt;&lt;xsiServerAddress&gt;test.server.com&lt;/xsiServerAddress&gt;&lt;/serverDetails&gt;&lt;/SampleDocument&gt;</DetailsResult>
  </DetailsResponse>
 </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>

Comment: Here you go: https://pastebin.com/zrKdq9nk. Also, it works the same on Android and plain Java

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/202873/discussion-between-loredan13-and-vineeth-kuttipurath-kottayodan).

Comment: Finally it worked. Thanks for your time and effort.

Comment: Can we read a blank xml tag exist using simple xml; I want to get 'read' exist for a status; xml below        
         <messageInfo>
  <duration>2040</duration>
  <read />
         </messageInfo>

Comment: @VineethKuttipurathkottayodan I think `@Element Object read;` should do it

Comment: I am always getting error while parsing additional details and its object :                                 <Group><startIndex>1</startIndex><numberOfRecords>40</numberOfRecords><groupDirectory><directoryDetails><firstName>test</firstName><additionalDetails><mobile>test</mobile><title>CTO</title></additionalDetails></directoryDetails><directoryDetails><firstName>test</firstName><additionalDetails><mobile>test</mobile></additionalDetails></directoryDetails><directoryDetails><firstName>test</firstName></directoryDetails></groupDirectory></Group>

Comment: Can you help me out

Comment: Can you look into it please. I tried many ways. But it doesn't work